# PHP: Can I suppress output of a function?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I know you can use output buffer. The problem right now is, I am using a function in a Wordpress plugin and it is automatically and it automatically outputs the return. However, I want to check the return to see if it is false or returning my data.

I have tried:

```
if( function_name() ) {

}

$name = function_name();
```

I can still see the output in those situations, which I why I wanted to suppress it and do some checks first. I don't want to edit the core function of the plugin, but I will as a last resort. Is there a better work around?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It can be done like this:

```
ob_start();
if (function_name()) { }
else {}

// then you can do one of the following
ob_end_clean(); // in case you want to suppress function_name output
ob_flush(); // in case you don't want to suppress function_name output
```

Have a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php) for more information about output control functions.

Also, instead of using `ob_flush` and `ob_end_clean` you could use [`ob_get_clean`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php).

Answer (score 0):

First, capture the output and return value of the function.

```
ob_start();
$name = function_name();
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Next, decide whether or not you want to output it.

```
if ($name !== false) {
    echo $output;
}
```

You weren't clear what you wanted to do with the return value if it wasn't `false` or if it was actually the output of the function that you wanted to send to the page.